# Remarks and notes in a single, raggedright paragraph with tabulararray

Tags: tabularray

How can I achieve have remarks and notes in a single, `\raggedright` paragraph when using `tabularray`? What I'm looking for is much the same behavior that we get from using `threeparttable` with the `para` and `flushleft` package options (see example below).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[para, flushleft]{threeparttable}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \begin{threeparttable}
      \caption{A \texttt{threeparttable} table}
      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}Xcc@{}}
        \hline
        & A & B \\
        \hline
        A row heading\tnote{a} & a & 123 \\
        Another row heading & b & 456 \\
        Yet another row heading & c & 789 \\
        \hline
      \end{tabularx}
      \begin{tablenotes}
        \emph{Note}: A few words describing something noteworthy.
        \item[a] A table footnote that goes on for a few words more than this.
      \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: threeparttable with para and flushleft package options]

My best crack at this has been to edit the definition of the "remark inline" template and remove the `\par` at the end (see example below). But this adds a horizontal space before the first remark and stretches the interword spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\DefTblrTemplate{remark}{inline-noclosingpar}{%Identical to the remark inline template except for the commented line
  \UseTblrAlign{remark}
  \UseTblrIndent{remark}
  \UseTblrHang{remark}
  \leavevmode
  \MapTblrRemarks
  {
    \UseTblrTemplate{remark-tag}{default}
    \UseTblrTemplate{remark-sep}{default}
    \UseTblrTemplate{remark-text}{default}
    \quad
  }
  % \par%Commented out to remove the row break between the remarks and the notes
}
\DefTblrTemplate{lastfoot}{mytemplate}{%
  \UseTblrTemplate{remark}{default}
  \UseTblrTemplate{note}{default}
}
\NewTblrTheme{mytheme}{
  \SetTblrTemplate{remark}{inline-noclosingpar}
  \SetTblrTemplate{note}{inline}
  \SetTblrTemplate{lastfoot}{mytemplate}
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \begin{talltblr}[
      theme=mytheme,
      caption={A \texttt{tabularray} table},
      remark{Note}={A few words describing something noteworthy.},
      note{a}={A table footnote that goes on for a few words more than this.}
    ]{
      colspec={@{}Xcc@{}},
      width=\linewidth
    }
      \hline
      & A & B \\
      \hline
      A row heading\TblrNote{a} & a & 123 \\
      Another row heading & b & 456 \\
      Yet another row heading & c & 789 \\
      \hline
    \end{talltblr}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: talltblr with custom footer template]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are differences in the format of notes and remarks between `tabularray` and `threeparttable`.
With a few redefinitions, they look pretty similar.

**Note:** I found it is very important to add  `%` after each line of the templates to avoid spurious spaces.

[image: z]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray} 

% emulate threeparttable <<<<<<<<<<
\DefTblrTemplate{remark-sep}{three}{:\space}
\DefTblrTemplate{note-sep}{three}{\,}   

\DefTblrTemplate{remark}{inline-noclosingpar}{% similar to the remark plain 
\MapTblrRemarks{%
    \noindent%
    \UseTblrTemplate{remark-tag}{default}%
    \UseTblrTemplate{remark-sep}{three}%
    \UseTblrTemplate{remark-text}{default}% 
    \space\space}
}

    
\DefTblrTemplate{note}{inline-three}{%
    \MapTblrNotes{%
        \noindent%
        \UseTblrTemplate{note-tag}{default}%
        \UseTblrTemplate{note-sep}{three}%
        \UseTblrTemplate{note-text}{default}%
        \space}
}

\DefTblrTemplate{lastfoot}{mytemplate}{%
    \UseTblrTemplate{remark}{inline-noclosingpar}%
    \UseTblrTemplate{note}{inline-three}%
}
\NewTblrTheme{mytheme}{%
    \SetTblrTemplate{lastfoot}{mytemplate}%
}
\begin{document}        

    \begin{table}
        \begin{talltblr}[
            theme=mytheme,
            caption={A \texttt{tabularray} table emulating a \texttt{threeparttable}},
            remark{Note}={A few words describing something noteworthy.},
            note{a}={A table footnote that goes on for a few words more than this.}
            ]{
                colspec={@{}Xcc@{}},
                width=\linewidth
            }
            \hline
            & A & B \\
            \hline
            A row heading\TblrNote{a} & a & 123 \\
            Another row heading & b & 456 \\
            Yet another row heading & c & 789 \\
            \hline
        \end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: zz]

Comment: This looks great! I have posted a [follow-up question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/616260/71332) :-)